# split json into multi columns dynamically python

Tags: python, sql, json, dynamic, split

I'm trying to extract an API response and make a table in SQL or a data frame in python.

the response is like this:

```
{'posts': [
{'ID': '15',
'Details': 'Hotel:Campsite;Message:Reservation inquiries '},

{'ID': '150',
'Details': 'Page:45-discount-y;PageLink:https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/?lang=en&source=Call%20Center'},

{'ID': '13',
'Details': ''}]}
```

There are a lot of keys or columns under the details. So I want a dynamic way to split the details into multiple columns as well

*The desired output:*

| ID | Details | Hotel | Message | Page | PageLink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Hotel:Campsite;Message:Reservation inquiries | Campsite | Reservation inquiries | NULL | NULL |
| 150 | Page:45-discount-y;PageLink:[https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/|](https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/%7C) NULL | NULL | 45-discount-y | [https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/|](https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/%7C) |  |
| 13 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {'posts': [
    {'ID': '15','Details': 'Hotel:Campsite;Message:Reservation inquiries '},
    {'ID': '150','Details': 'Page:45-discount-y;PageLink:https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/?lang=en&source=Call%20Center'},
    {'ID': '13','Details': ''}
]}

all_data = []
for p in dct['posts']:
    all_data.append({'ID':p['ID'], 'Details':p['Details'], **dict(v.split(':', maxsplit=1) for v in p['Details'].split(';') if v)})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | ID | Details | Hotel | Message | Page | PageLink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | Hotel:Campsite;Message:Reservation inquiries | Campsite | Reservation inquiries | nan | nan |
| 1 | 150 | Page:45-discount-y;PageLink:https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/?lang=en&source=Call%20Center | nan | nan | 45-discount-y | https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/?lang=en&source=Call%20Center |
| 2 | 13 |  | nan | nan | nan | nan |